# Matrix proof $A ^ { - 1 } \mathrm { x } = \frac { 1 } { \lambda } \mathrm { x }$

Tags: matrices

Prove that, if $A$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix and $A \mathrm { x } = \lambda \mathrm { x }$ for some non-zero
n-vector $\mathrm { x }$ and some scalar $\lambda ,$ then

$A ^ { - 1 } \mathbf { x } = \frac { 1 } { \lambda } \mathbf { x }.$

So I did simple algebra, but I don't know if the inverse of A can equal the reciprocal of $\lambda$ here:

$A x = \lambda x$

$A = \lambda$

$A ^ { - 1 } = \lambda ^ { - 1 }$

$A ^ { - 1 } = \frac { 1 } { \lambda }$

$\therefore A ^ { - 1 } x = \frac { 1 } { \lambda } x$

Comment: @user376343 Even with that correction, the step in the derivation is still erroneous. You can’t conclude from $Ax=\lambda x$ for _some_ $x$ that $A=\lambda I$.

Comment: Right @amd Thinking correctly, writing wrongly.

Answer (score 3):

You can't say $A=\lambda$, because $A$ is a matrix and $\lambda$ is a number. Even if you write the equality as $A\mathbf{x}=(\lambda I)\mathbf{x}$ you ***cannot*** deduce that $A=\lambda I$ ($I$ the identity matrix), but just that $\mathbf{x}$ belongs to the null space of $A-\lambda I$.

---

First observe that $\lambda\ne0$, otherwise $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, contradicting $A$ being invertible. Then multiply by $A^{-1}$, so
$$
\mathbf{x}=A^{-1}(\lambda\mathbf{x})=\lambda(A^{-1}\mathbf{x})
$$
Now multiply by $\lambda^{-1}$:
$$
\lambda^{-1}\mathbf{x}=A^{-1}\mathbf{x}
$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
Ax &= \lambda x\\
A^{-1} A x &= A^{-1} \lambda x\\
\frac{1}{\lambda} x &= A^{-1} x
\end{align}

First left-multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$. Then the $A$ and $A^{-1}$ cancel on the left side. Then multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ to get your result.

Comment: Omg , its so clear now , thanks to think I raised a matrix to the power -1 *face palm*

Answer (score 1):

That does not work, you can't take an inverse of a vector. Right now at some point it says a matrix ($A$) is equal to a scalar ($\lambda$). Rather use that
$$x=A^{-1}Ax=\lambda A^{-1}x$$
We can now divide by $\lambda$ on both sides to get $\frac{1}{\lambda}x=A^{-1}x$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply $Ax=\lambda x$ by $A^{-1}$ on both sides, then
$$x=\lambda A^{-1}x$$ and, since $A$ is invertible, $\lambda \neq 0.$ So we can divide by $\lambda.$